# Does Facebook know I'm scraping it with PhantomJS and can it change its website to counter me?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

So, maybe I'm being paranoid.

I'm scraping my Facebook timeline for a hobby project using PhantomJS. Basically, I wrote a program that finds all of my ads by querying the page for the text `Sponsored` with XPATH inside of phantom's `page.evaluate` block. The text was being displayed as innerHTML of html `a` elements.

Things were working great for a few days and it was finding tons of ads.

Then it stopped returning any results.

When I logged into Facebook manually to inspect the elements again, I found that the word `Sponsored` was now appearing on the page in an `::after` pseudoclass element with the css property `content: sponsored`. This means that an XPATH query for the text no longer yields any results. No joke, Facebook seemed to have changed the way they rendered this word after being scraped for a couple days.

Paranoid. I told you.

So, I offer this question to the community of Javascript, Web-Scraping, and PhantomJS developers out there. What the heck is going on. Can Facebook know what my PhantomJS program is doing inside of the `page.evaluate` block?

If so, how? Would my phantom commands appear in a key logger program embedded in the page, for instance?

What are some of your theories?

Comment: So you think an HTML change was a result of your scrapping the site? Maybe they just redesigned it......Put away your tin foil hat.

Comment: I know my tin foil hat isn't as cool as your Viking one :) but can you answer if this is at least possible to detect what a PhantomJS scraper is doing on your site?

Comment: Can they detect it is phantom..... yes.... do they know what it is doing? Well they can log actions just like how anyone can track anything on a webpage, but the code... no... But now facebook knows....

Comment: I think the part of your question that is missing is: Are you spoofing a browser user agent when you make the calls? If not, I am sure they can read the PhantomJS string that is set up which most sites look for when testing for scrapers. I know many companies just redirect calls based on user agents. I worked for one that redirected it to a site that basically said, use the free api to download the content instead of scraping.

Comment: I was spoofing yes, it was a (I think) generic agent -  `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36`

Comment: And theoretically, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that Facebook has a sophisticated system to counter scraping. It does have to remain in compliance with its advertisement-buying customers. They're being paid to show ads to *humans not *bots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to detect PhantomJS even if the useragent is spoofed. 
There are plenty of litte ways in which it differs from other browsers, among others:

- Wrong order of headers
- Lack of media plugins and latest JS capabilities
- PhantomJS-specific methods, like `window.callPhantom`
- PhantomJS name in the stack trace

and many others.

Please refer to this excellent article and presentation linked there for details: https://blog.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/22/detecting-phantomjs-based-visitors/

Maybe [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) would be a better fit for your needs as it is based on a real cutting-edge Chromium browser.

Comment: Not really what OP is asking.... Tin Foli Hat is asking if they can see his code that is running.

Comment: Please think about it @epascarello : it they know it's a bot, they can track what it's doing. So yes it's possible, although not really probable.

Comment: But it is not going to know that there is code reading part of the page.... It can detect scrolling, what was clicked, loaded. It is going to have no clue it looked at the content of the page.

Comment: I never asked if it can see my code. If someone with an understanding of PhantomJS were to answer instead of you, maybe they can answer how the `page.evaluate` block runs its commands and what that looks like to a website and how a website can detect these commands.

Comment: If it fires events to scroll, click, key events, etc, yes they can log that. But when you have it read text on the page... no. Just like how you can load it up in the console and they can not detect that you are reading it.

Comment: If one could override js native functions like `querySelectorAll` they **could** even track what you're reading, but it's not allowed for security reasons (although didn't test this in PhantomJS). But — if they know it's a bot, they could at least try to thwart his actions like scraping or... I dunno, clicking on ads, maybe?

Comment: So directly answering the question: yes can know you're scraping it and yes it can change the site code for you.

Comment: Thanks @Vaviloff that article you linked to was great and your insight very helpful.